# facing error while pasting GitHub repository URL in Jenkins server

Tags: cicd

An internal error occurred during form field validation (HTTP 500). Please reload the page and if the problem persists, ask the administrator for help.

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure you input the right authorization keys. If only there was a simpler way to onboard repositories rather than going back to and fro copy-pasting stuff! Else, you can go through documentations of other platforms for onboarding repos, mostly it would all be the same. Like this one: https://docs.ozone.one/ozone-end-user-guide/